# Line break problem on simple PySimpleGUI program

Tags: python, line-breaks, pysimplegui

So I am very new to programming and this is my very first independent program on PySimpleGUI. It went fine for a while, and I managed to get all I wanted, except to a small mistake: I can't line break on the sg.Text() with \n. Here's what the program was (is) supposed to be (the text in the code isn't in English):

A simple window appears asking the user for two inputs: the number they want the table and until what number they want the table. Then, the user clicks the 'TABLE' (tabuar) and another window appears, showing the table of the number asked. The problem shows up on the second window:
I wanted the table to show up like that (* being the numbers): 1x* = * (line break) 2x* = * (line break) and so on. It shows, instead, like this: 1x* = * 2x** = ** with no line break.

I searched it up, put \n in every place possible, and nothing worked. All I want is it to have the correct spacing. Really simple. I think the problem is that I used a loop (because the number of tables it shows varies depending on user input) or something like that. Help me out?

This is the main block that includes the problem itself (notice that I got it off from the bigger while true block):

TABUAR is the button you click to show the table, values[1] is the value you input how many tables, and values[0] is the number itself.

```
    if event == 'TABUAR':
        maximo = int(values[1])+1
        numero = int(values[0])
        layout = [[sg.Text(f'{i}x{numero} = {i*numero}\n')for i in range(1, maximo)],
                  [sg.Button('SAIR')]
                  ]
        window = sg.Window('TABUADA', layout)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the question is, following code demo the answer.

If you need more `Text` elements lined vertically, `'\n'` won't be shown here for the height of `Text` element is only 1.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def sub_window(number, tables):

    layout = [
        [sg.Text(f'{i+1}x{number} = {(i+1)*number}')] for i in range(tables)] + [
        [sg.Push(), sg.Button('OK')],
    ]
    sg.Window('Sub Window', layout, modal=True).read(close=True)

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Number'), sg.Push(), sg.Input(key='Number')],
    [sg.Text('Tables'), sg.Push(), sg.Input(key='Tables')],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Submit')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Submit':
        try:
            number, tables = int(values['Number']), int(values['Tables'])
        except ValueError:
            sg.popup('Wrong integer !', title='Error Message')
            continue
        sub_window(number, tables)

window.close()
```

[image]

If you need more lines to show the `Text` element, you can set the option `size` of the `Text` element, like `(None, 2)`, the `'\n'` will be shown.

```py
    layout = [
        [sg.Text(f'{i+1}x{number} = {(i+1)*number}\n', size=(None, 2))] for i in range(tables)] + [
        [sg.Push(), sg.Button('OK')],
    ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the Multi-line element, It is nice to set the size with the expected height, or the minimal height and allow the scroll bars to do the rest. In the example below I have set the size to the smaller of # of rows or 10; therefore if user requests more than 10 rows the scroll bar will allow him to see 10 rows at a time.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def sub_window(rows, multiplier):
    lines = "\n".join(f'{i + 1}x{multiplier} = {(i + 1) * multiplier}' for i in range(rows))
    layout = [[sg.Multiline(lines, size=(60, min(rows,10)))],
              [sg.Push(), sg.Button('OK'), sg.Push()]]
    sg.Window('Sub Window', layout, modal=True).read(close=True)


layout = [
    [sg.Text('Rows'), sg.Push(), sg.Input('7', key='ROWS')],
    [sg.Text('Multiplier'), sg.Push(), sg.Input('5', key='MULTIPLIER')],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Submit'), sg.Push()],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Submit':
        try:
            rows, multiplier = int(values['ROWS']), int(values['MULTIPLIER'])
        except ValueError:
            sg.popup('Wrong integer !', title='Error Message')
            continue
        sub_window(rows, multiplier)
window.close()
```

As a hint: use the `key='--Sample--'` property for every element that you will read the value and then use `value['--Sample--']` to read that element's value.  It is not wise to access the values with the default numbers.